# Dynamic programming: maximize the number of things to be bought

Tags: dynamic-programming

For example, for a product, we have a list of the number of products you buy and the corresponding price you pay with this number of products:

number = {1, 5, 8, 12}

price  = {0.5, 2, 3, 3.6} 
 (i.e. you pay 0.5 for 1 product, 2 for 5 products and so on)

Now I need to use a fixed number of dollars to buy as many number of products as possible. How do I do this using dynamic programming?

I understand how I minimize the cost if I have a fixed number of products I want to buy. But for a fixed amount of money, I get confused, since the price is of type double, I cannot do this with indexing the an array with the prices.

Comment: Currency should never use floating-point variables, due to rounding  problems. Just put all your prices in cents (1/100 of one dollar), and you have an integer problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a binary search on the number of product and then minimize the cost with that fixed number of products.

It can be also solved using greedy I think. Store **pricePerProduct = price[i] / number[i]** , **price[i]** , **number[i]** in an array and Sort the array . Traverse the array . For ith index you can buy **floor( remainingDollar / price[i] ) * number[i]** number of products. remainingDollar will be updated to **floor( remainingDollar / price[i] ) * price[i]**